# JAVA MissingFormatArgumentException: Printing an array that is passed in method parameters

Tags: java, arrays, object, exception, parameter-passing

This class contains two classes in which I am testing. While the latter one is purely the test class. These java files are incorporated into one package and then complied on Netbeans.

```
package Tester;

class Point 
{
private double x;
private double y;

public Point()
{
    x = 0.0;
    y = 0.0;
}

public Point(double x, double y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void setXCoordinate(double x)
{
    this.x = x;
}

public void setYCoordinate(double y)
{
    this.y = y;
}

public void printPoint()
{
    System.out.printf("(x,y): (%f,%f)");
}

public void printPoint(Point[] array)
{
    for(Point p: array)
        p.printPoint();
}
}

public class Quadrilateral 
{
Point[] array;

public Quadrilateral(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4)
{
    array = new Point[4];
    
    array[0].setXCoordinate(x1);
    array[0].setYCoordinate(y1);
    
    array[1].setXCoordinate(x2);
    array[1].setYCoordinate(y2);
    
    array[2].setXCoordinate(x3);
    array[2].setYCoordinate(y3);
    
    array[3].setXCoordinate(x4);
    array[3].setYCoordinate(y4);     
}


public Quadrilateral(Point[] points)
{
    array = points;
}

public void printQuadrilateral()
{
    for(Point p: array)
            p.printPoint();
}

}
```

*Tester class

```
package Tester;

public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Point[] array = new Point[4];
    Point p1 = new Point(3.5,4.2);
    Point p2 = new Point(3.6,4.6);
    Point p3 = new Point(3.5,4.7);
    Point p4 = new Point(3.3,4.3);
    
    array[0] = p1;
    array[1] = p2;
    array[2] = p3;
    array[3] = p4;
    
    Quadrilateral q = new Quadrilateral(array);
    q.printQuadrilateral();
}

}
```

So basically I am trying to establish a quadrilateral by passing it four points (which for right now doesn't have to make a quadrilateral). I created two constructors which initialize the Quadrilateral object by different means. The second constructor which is passed an array(which is already declared and initialize) is suppose to be associated as the quadrilateral object four points. However when i attempt to print the Quadrilateral's points(printQuadrilateral()) it throws formatting errors which does not happen when the first constructor is caled and printQuadrilateral() is called. Please help me understand what is going on. Here are the errors:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format    specifier '%f'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2519)
(x,y): (    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at Tester.Point.printPoint(Quadrilateral.java:32)
    at Tester.Quadrilateral.printQuadrilateral(Quadrilateral.java:75)
    at Tester.Tester.main(Tester.java:44)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you expect the statement to do?

```
System.out.printf("(x,y): (%f,%f)");
```

You never gave any values. Try actually giving some values for the `%f` markers:

```
System.out.printf("(x,y): (%f,%f)", this.x, this.y);
```

You should read the The Java™ Tutorials: [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Comment: Such a simple mistake that I thought I had fix. It was originally a println statement. Thank you